# COM pointer to struct

Tags: c#, com, interop, struct

I'm using Visual Studio 2008/.NET 3.5. I used VS to make a COM component interoperable in .NET. I added a reference from the application to the COM DLL. The COM DLL is a 3rd party object - part of an SDK.

For all methods and events everything is working just fine - COM objects/events are represented as a first class .NET objects/events.

Here is what is happening:

The Scan() method runs. At the end of it's execution it raises an event.

```
void scanner_ImageBuffer(int lStructure)
{
}
```

The argument - lStructure - according to the documentation is:

```
ImageBuffer( int lStructure )
```

> Description: The ImageBuffer event
>   will notify the client application of
>   the completion of a scan and pass a
>   structure containing the width,
>   height, size, and image buffer of the
>   image that was collected as part of
>   the scan.  It is the responsibility of
>   the client application to free the
>   memory that was allocated for the
>   image buffer and to free the memory
>   for the structure.  This event may not
>   be compatible with Visual Basic
>   applications. Parameters:
>
> The int lStructure is a 32-bit pointer
>   to the following structure

```
struct _ImageBufferDef
{
    int lWidth;   // size of the image width in pixels
    int lHeight;  // size of the image height in pixels
    int lSize;    // size of the image in bytes
    unsigned short* pusBuffer;  // allocated memory containing image
}
```

> Here is where I'm stuck: **How do I
>   reconstruct the object with only a
>   int?**

---

I have tried:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct ImageBufferDef
{
    int lWidth;
    int lHeight;
    int lSize;
    IntPtr pusBuffer;
}

void scanner_ImageBuffer( int lStructure )
{
    IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr( lStructure );

    ImageBufferDef buf = new ImageBufferDef();

    try
    {
        Marshal.PtrToStructure( ptr, buf );
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when you call `Marhsal.PtrToStructure()`? Does it throw an exception or is the returned ImageBufferDef filled with garbage?

Comment: Throws an exception. However, this is working: <code>ImageBufferDef bufferDef = (ImageBufferDef) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(ImageBufferDef));</code>

How can I now get at the nested IntPtr pusBuffer?

Comment: How do you highlight code in Comments?

Answer (score 0):

Because of

```
int lSize;    // size of the image in bytes
unsigned short* pusBuffer;  // allocated memory containing image
```

After

```
ImageBufferDef bufferDef = (ImageBufferDef)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(ImageBufferDef));
```

you can try

```
short[] buffer = new short[bufferDef.lSize / 2];
Marshal.Copy(bufferDef.pusBuffer, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

In case you'll change the `buffer` array type, be carefull about its length and the `Marshal.Copy` `length` parameter, because the first have to take into account the array element size that is **2** being it an `short[]`, and the second wants the element count of the array instead of the total byte count.